# Conflict errors (409) when creating documents with Automatic ID generation on Lazy-indexed collection

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I use DocumentDB with the [.NET SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet) on a collection for which I set a custom indexing policy using `IndexingMode.Lazy`. This provides me *eventual consistency* for all operations on the collection.

I want to do upsert-like operation on non-critical data : I can afford duplicates and missed updates.

I use code like this :

```cs
public async Task UpsertChunk(MyChunk chunk)
{
    var id = _documentClient
                    .CreateDocumentQuery<PersistentChunk>()
                    .Where(c => c.ChunkKey == chunk.ChunkKey)
                    .Select(c => c.id)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

    var persistentChunk = chunk.ToPersistentChunk();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
        await _documentClient.CreateDocumentAsync(_collectionUri, persistentChunk);
    }
    else
    {
        persistentChunk.id = id;
        var uri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(_databaseId, _collectionId, id);
        await _documentClient.ReplaceDocumentAsync(uri, persistentChunk);
    }
}
```

I get, *non-consistently*, **Conflict errors** : `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException: Message: {"Errors":["Resource with specified id or name already exists"]}`

However, since I use **Automatic ID Generation**, it should not be possible to have duplicate ids, even in the case of concurrent writes.

Has anyone encountered this kind of behavior before ? 
I suspect this could be triggered by retries executed by the .NET SDK if successful writes are not acknowledged as such by DocumentDB.

Comment: What does `ToPersistentChunk` do? Are you setting the `id` property before calling `CreateDocumentAsync` or leaving it empty?

Comment: It basically does a copy of the initial `chunk` into a serializable type.
I suspect my issue has to do with internal retries made by the SDK and eventual consistency : I suspect we sometimes get 429 errors even if the document is correctly created.

Answer (score 0):

> Conflict errors : Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException: Message: {"Errors":["Resource with specified id or name already exists"]}

[409 Conflict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/http-status-codes-for-documentdb) indicates the id provided for a resource on a PUT or POST operation has been taken by an existing resource. Please try to query documents by **id property** instead of **ChunkKey property**, and then you could determine to add/replace document based on the query result `num`.

```
var num = client.CreateDocumentQuery<MyChunk>("dbs/{your db}/colls/{your collection}").Where(c => c.id == chunk.id).AsEnumerable().Count();
```